# Sublime Text 3 not opening on macOS Mojave

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-3

I'm on a macOS Mojave.

For some strange reason, Sublime Text 3 is not opening. When I try to open it, it closes right away, before the window even shows up. It was working yesterday, but now it's not working, and I haven't changed any files whatsoever.
I have tried uninstalling and installing it again. Didn’t work.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Comment: @JakeGould 3 times...

Comment: When you uninstalled it did you remove anything from ~/Library?

Comment: @overfl0w Go download [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) and try doing this: Make sure you have Sublime Text 3 installed, then drag it onto AppCleaner. It will make sure to delete utterly all items—configs and such—and when you drag it onto the app, it should show you all the items it will delete. Then just confirm that and try installing Sublime Text 3 again. If that doesn’t work, try installing [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) and clear your system caches. Reboot, reinstall Sublime Text 3 and try again.

Comment: @JakeGould I also tried using AppCleaner,but for some reason its not working, it says “(App) couln’t be removed” or something like that. Instead, I manually deleted all the files shown in AppCleaner. And I will give Onyx a try, thanks.

Comment: I `rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3` and that got it working back for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never-mind... All I had to do is go on *Disk Utility* and press on *First Aid*. It solved the problem.

---

I will keep this here for anyone who has the same problem as I did.